# Git error: Failed to connect to <IP> port <Port>: Connection timed out

Tags: server, connection, git

whenever the command:

```
git push origin master
```

is given, the following error is shown:

```
Failed to connect to 172.16.0.16 port 8080: Connection timed out
```

I have tried connecting to several networks but I am encountering the same error all the time.
I am new to git and Linux and can't understand these errors properly.
Please help

[image: terminalscreen in the image]

Comment: Are you using a firewall?

Comment: Looks like that's not a GitHub IP address. It should be either 192.30.252.0/22 or 185.199.108.0/22. See [GitHub's IP addresses](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ip-addresses/)

Comment: @George I am not using firewall.

Comment: @wjandrea How do I change the IP then?

Comment: I don't know if this is a good idea, but you could change the remote url. I think `https://192.30.253.112/$username/myfirstrepo.git` could work.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: There must be some sort of networking device blocking the connection, because 172.16/12 is a private range (i.e. reserved for LANs).